# Writing code to update a large matrix?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, logic

How can I write a code to update a matrix based on certain rules? I plan on constructing a large matrix, and I cannot submit entries one by one.

The rules for the matrix are as followed:

$$
 P(i,j)=
\begin{cases}
p,  & \text{if $j$ = $2i$}\land m \\
q, & \text{if $j$ = $(2i-m)$ }\lor 0
\end{cases}
$$

P is square. I was thinking of just defining it to be a 0 matrix first, then updating the values with whatever code. However, I can't seem to think of how that would be done. I've never heard of updating a matrix. For a given $m$, how would one generate such matrix in Mathematica? Could someone list an example?

Answer (score 3):

```
m = 5;
sa = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == Min[2 i, m] :> 
    p, {i_, j_} /; j == 2 i - m :> q}, {m, m}]
```

[image]

```
mat = Partition[Range[m^2], m];
sa2 = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == Min[2 i, m] :> p, 
    {i_, j_} /; j == 2 i - m, 0] :> q, 
    {i_, j_} :> mat[[i, j]]}, {m, m}];
Row[MatrixForm /@ {mat, sa2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to update values; you can use `Table` and create it in one pass.

```
m = 4;
Table[
    Which[
        j == 2 i && j == m, p,
        j == 2 i - m || j == 0, q,
        True, 0
    ], {i, 10}, {j, 10}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating an existing matrix

```
randomP = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {5, 5}];

m = 2

ReplacePart[randomP, {{i_, j_} /; And[j == 2 i, j == m] -> p, 
                      {i_, j_} /; Or[j == 2 i - m, j == 0] -> q}]
```

[image]